# Strange CMD Evironment Variable Behavior

Tags: java, windows, command-line, cmd

So I was trying to set my JAVA_HOME variable for a program and though I was sure I set the right directory the program was printing:

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

I did some testing and now I'm just baffled. 
[image: Terminal Output]

Other info:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin>java.exe -version
java version "1.7.0_60"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_60-b19)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.60-b09, mixed mode)
```

Windows version

```
OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 8.1 Pro
OS Version:                6.3.9600 N/A Build 9600
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `cd` command handles paths with spaces but `dir` requires that you quote the path if it contains spaces.

```
dir "%JAVA_HOME%"
```

will do what you expect.

The issue is that `cd` expects only one path, so even if the path contains a space it's still treated as a single string.  `dir` can handle multiple paths, delimited by spaces, so when `%JAVA_HOME%` gets expanded you get

```
dir C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin
```

which contains TWO paths (as seen by the dir command), neither of which exists:

```
C:\Program
Files\Java\jre7\bin
```

Comment: now how do i set %JAVA_HOME% so that dir %JAVA_HOME% works? Because setx JAVA_HOME "[path]" does not work.

Comment: @ca.adamgordon why do you need to do this? Anyway it can be done by escaping double quotes: `SETX [options] JAVA_HOME ""C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin""`, or you can use the short name (MS-DOS name): `SETX [options] JAVA_HOME C:\PROGRA~1\Java\jre7\bin`

Comment: a cmd script, that I did not write, is using the variable to find the location of java.exe and its failing just like dir was. the `C:\PROGRA~1\...` works like a charm